# SwiftUI .onDrag pass to parent view on List

Tags: list, swiftui

I'm trying to do .onDrag on an item, and works well when I'm inside a LazyVGrid but once I'm inside a List it try to grab the parent view instead of my view.

How can I disable onDrag on the List Section so that user can drag the myImage inside the list Section like it happens once myimage is outside a list?

Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            myimage()
        }
        List{
            Section(content: {
                myimage()
            })
        }
    }
}
struct myimage: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .background(Color.pink).onDrag({ NSItemProvider() })
    }
}

struct MyView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image of what happens inside list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km4qG.png)

What I expected to happen, the same as with the my image that is outside the List:
[image of what happens outside list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abssF.png)

Can this be achieved inside list? Thanks.